# Github not showing my pages exactly as viewed locally

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, github

[This is github published page `ayushanand593.github.io/marcoIndia`](https://ayushanand593.github.io/marcoIndia/)

[This is actual index.html file](https://github.com/ayushanand593/marcoIndia/blob/main/index.html)

[This is actual css file.](https://github.com/ayushanand593/marcoIndia/blob/main/CSS/style.css)

Why the CSS file is not used at all when rendering the index.html page on Github Pages?

Comment: Is the problem that it's scrolling when it shouldn't be?

Comment: Please update your question with a clear definition of the problem.

Comment: When you will open the github published page the images are all big and the bootstrap cards are not padded.The colors of css are not applied.But when the index.html file is opened on my brwoser locally it works perfectly.

Comment: When you see the published github page the images are all big and alignment is distorted.Bootstrap cards are not padded and css font colors are not applied.But when you see the index.html file locally then everything is great the website looks like the way I created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first if the path used tp reference the CSS stylesheet is case-sensitive.

Your repository uses [`CSS/style.css`](https://github.com/ayushanand593/marcoIndia/blob/fbd3e1f47474fd38e7811c3b404a5f9989ab90b6/CSS/style.css), but your [`index.html`](https://github.com/ayushanand593/marcoIndia/blob/fbd3e1f47474fd38e7811c3b404a5f9989ab90b6/index.html#L5) uses:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
                             ^^^
```